# How to access google drive use oauth2.0 and objective c

Tags: objective-c, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I download the google-api-objectivec-client-read-only.zip from google developer and I import the lib to my xcode project.But I don't know how to use the google-api-objective-client to access the google drive with oauth2.
My code:

```
- (void)oauth2access {
  // Load the OAuth 2 token from the keychain, if it was previously saved.
  NSString *clientID = [_clientIDField stringValue];
  NSString *clientSecret = [_clientSecretField stringValue];

  GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
  auth = [GTMOAuth2WindowController authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                            clientID:clientID
                                                        clientSecret:clientSecret];
  self.driveService.authorizer = auth;

  // Set the result text fields to have a distinctive color and mono-spaced font.
  [_fileListResultTextField setTextColor:[NSColor darkGrayColor]];
  [_detailResultTextField setTextColor:[NSColor darkGrayColor]];

  NSFont *resultTextFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:9];
  [_fileListResultTextField setFont:resultTextFont];
  [_detailResultTextField setFont:resultTextFont];

  [self updateUI];
}
```

Run the program,the program crashed.
How to access google drive use objc with oauth2?

Comment: what steps you are following for google drive implementation

Comment: Did you got the answer? Please give answer.